# Consensus-Criminal Justice

Tags: criminal-law, common-law

How is it possible to have a consensus about what should or should not be legal in a country with several hundred million people from all races, religions, and walks of life?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [politics.se].

Comment: Consensus does not mean unanimity

Answer (score 2):

There isn't necessarily consensus. Legislation is passed by rough majority of the elected representatives, and signed into law by the chief executive (President or Governor) unless they choose to veto it.

Legislators and executives can be replaced by election if enough of the people want them gone.